# Google Chrome Update - Issue with copying code from Inspector CSS

Tags: google-chrome, sublimetext3

I have no idea why this has started happening but it is very annoying...

Basically, now when I copy CSS from Google Chrome Inspector, it formats it as follows:

```
border-radius: 50%;
    width: 26
px
;
    height: 26
px
;
    color: transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
```

Instead of how it's always worked like so:

```
border-radius: 50%;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
color: transparent;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

EDIT: I think it's to do with the latest Chrome update...

It seems it now has an option to set which metric you want to use, i.e. PX, EM etc...

Can this be disabled somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 25):

It used to copy normally, now it takes those silly breaks.

I found this - https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7125792

If you select CSS and Copy (Ctrl+C) it's broken, but if you use right-click > copy it's clean format.

[image]

//Hey, I have a solution. The Chromium developers have fixed it in the latest update .96 (it is not known when it will be stable) - until then, you just need to download Google Chrome Canary - it is fixed there. For now the stable version (with faulty CSS copying) is .95, please wait for the .96 update.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I've had to start doing, so annoying they didn't add a way to disable that though.

Comment: Reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1262889

Comment: Hey, I have a solution. The Chromium developers have fixed it in the latest update .96 (it is not known when it will be stable) - until then, you just need to download Google Chrome Canary - it is fixed there. For now the stable version (with faulty CSS copying) is .95, please wait for the .96 update.

Comment: FYI, on the chrome website it says version 96 will be stable November 16.

Comment: So this means, after such big bug, we need to wait 34 days to get a fix? Unbelievable...

Comment: @ViliusL in Google Chrome Beta it is fixed there, Google Chrome Canary too.

Comment: @DamianSzymański i know it, but does all world developers should download beta or nightly, which probably has other issues? What I am saying, that there had to be faster way to push fixes.

Answer (score 9):

By reading the comments on the following bug report, I guess they're going to rollback this feature and go back to plaintext CSS editing.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259088

Many people are complaining so we may have a setting in the future to enable/disable that.

Answer (score 1):

using this method to disable css length problem.

You can disable it via the **Settings > Experiments > Enable CSS length authoring tools in the Styles pane checkbox.**