# How can I solve the problem of copy/pasting the CSS property and value in inspect element both Chrome and Brave?

Tags: html, css, inspect, inspect-element

I recently try to Copy and Paste CSS code and this occurred
this a simple copy Ctrl+c
[image]

and this is a simple paste Ctrl+v

[image]

but the result looks like this:

[image]

is there any way to prevent this and have simple Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v?

Comment: It's a bug in chrome and brave

Comment: Have you tried `copy rule` instead?

Comment: @disinfor of course but when you are creating a large project normal copy paste will come handy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome Update - Issue with copying code from Inspector CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735342/google-chrome-update-issue-with-copying-code-from-inspector-css)

Comment: yes downgrade was good and I did that thanks let wait for Chrome Developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **'copy all declarations'** or **'copy rule'** in inspect element until they fix this issue.

**copy rule**: it would copy **selectors + properties + values**

**copy all declarations**: it would copy **properties + values** not selectors

**simple copy result:**

[image]

---

**But with copy all declarations or copy rule:**

[image]

**result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For chrome:-**

As long as you can get focus in the `Styles` pane, you can use `Ctrl` + `A` to select all, then `Ctrl` + `C` to copy as usual.

I find it's easiest to click in the bottom-right corner of one of the listed styles to avoid giving focus to a rule in the style (which would prevent you from selecting more than that rule). See the red circle in the picture below to see where I normally click. Admittedly it will usually take a few attempts; just keep trying to select all and adjusting where you click until it works.

[image]

**And for brave:-**

Go to inspect than selete what you need than `ctrl` + `c` than past it on your editor using `ctrl` + `p`

[image]

Comment: thanks, but the problem is on pasting those and this problem occurs only on CSS properties like margin/padding/border

Comment: Ya i think you got it  your answer from Saeed Nazari