# Line Breaks are Inserted when Copying CSS Rules from Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, copy-paste

I want to copy CSS rules from the Chrome (95.0.4638.54) Developer Tools, as I used to (until recently) but now there are line breaks added in between. Any fix?

### Example

What I want when pasted (and used to happen):

```
border: 0.1vmin solid #a7875d;
```

What's happening:

```
border: 0.1
vmin
 solid #a7875d;
```

Comment: It's a bug in chrome and brave

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome Update - Issue with copying code from Inspector CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735342/google-chrome-update-issue-with-copying-code-from-inspector-css)

Comment: @Rana - yes, I found it after posting my question, and flagged my question as duplicate. thanks!