# How to turn off the new size indicator for elements on Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Currently, I am running Google Chome Version 95.0.4638.54.

There is this new feature within the dev tools when inspecting DOM elements a size select dropdown appears next to any css property. I typically adjust css within the dev tools then copy and paste this into my css file, however, with this new dropdown feature it is difficult to copy and after pasting it insets new lines in the code ... where I have to then manually remove them.

How do I turn off this feature? It doesn't do me any service.

Screen shot of what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: [Google Chrome Update - Issue with copying code from Inspector CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735342/google-chrome-update-issue-with-copying-code-from-inspector-css)

It is a bug and it was fixed but it is not stable yet. You can use either Canary version or manually copy it from dev tools.